# Stock ticker symbol lookup API

Tags: api, finance, stocks

Is there any sort of API that just offers a simple symbol lookup service? i.e., input a company name and it will tell you the ticker symbol? I've tried just screen-scraping Google Finance, but after a little while it rate limits you and you have to enter a CAPTCHA. I'm trying to batch-lookup about 2000 ticker symbols. Any ideas?

Comment: No better luck with Yahoo Finance?

Comment: You need to add a delay between lookups. Say 5 seconds.

Comment: This script might be useful: https://github.com/kevin91nl/scrape-ticker-symbols

Comment: I did a recent evaluation of available trading APIs. http://www.strategic-options.com/insight/the-best-and-worst-stock-and-option-trading-apis/

Comment: This one does exactly what you want and it is updated daily https://rapidapi.com/logicione/api/stock-ticker-security-and-company-search-database?endpoint=apiendpoint_c9c32d57-dede-4507-b180-9ea4a61ebb02

Comment: I use https://github.com/portfolioplus/pytickersymbols the package offers an offline collection of many stock symbols.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use yahoo's symbol lookup like so:

> http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=yahoo&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback

Where *query* is the company name.

You'll get something like this in return:

```
YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback(
{
    "ResultSet": {
        "Query": "ya",
        "Result": [
            {
                "symbol": "YHOO",
                "name": "Yahoo! Inc.",
                "exch": "NMS",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "NASDAQ"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "AUY",
                "name": "Yamana Gold, Inc.",
                "exch": "NYQ",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "NYSE"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "YZC",
                "name": "Yanzhou Coal Mining Co. Ltd.",
                "exch": "NYQ",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "NYSE"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "YRI.TO",
                "name": "YAMANA GOLD INC COM NPV",
                "exch": "TOR",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Toronto"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "8046.TW",
                "name": "NAN YA PRINTED CIR TWD10",
                "exch": "TAI",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Taiwan"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "600319.SS",
                "name": "WEIFANG YAXING CHE 'A'CNY1",
                "exch": "SHH",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Shanghai"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "1991.HK",
                "name": "TA YANG GROUP",
                "exch": "HKG",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Hong Kong"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "1303.TW",
                "name": "NAN YA PLASTIC TWD10",
                "exch": "TAI",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Taiwan"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "0294.HK",
                "name": "YANGTZEKIANG",
                "exch": "HKG",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Hong Kong"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "YAVY",
                "name": "Yadkin Valley Financial Corp.",
                "exch": "NMS",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "NASDAQ"
            }
        ]
    }
}
)
```

Which is JSON and very easy to work with.

*Hush... don't tell anybody.*

Comment: hey is it possible to use wild char in the query? tried % and * but no luck...

Comment: this returns a maximum of 10 results in JSON !!!! How can we bypass this limitation of ONLY 10 results ??

Comment: thank you so much! is there a way to return pure JSON from yahoo finance if the query is a stock symbol instead of a name?

Comment: Also looking for a solution to bypass the limit of 10 results. Any ideas?

Comment: As of a few days ago, this solution seems to be broken. Yahoo now requires a "region" parameter, and setting it to "US" doesn't make any difference. If anybody has a workaround, I would love to hear it!

Comment: seems like they added 2 additional param,"region" and "lang". try the following http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=yhoo&region=1&lang=en&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback

Comment: And now it doesn't support fuzzy search anymore, it can only lookup "Exactly" symbol. :( Anyone has the workaround or any hidden parameter to turn on the fuzzy search feature?

Comment: This answer shows how to get the same functionality as before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32943831/1571826

Comment: For anyone else looking for this...Nothing I found was that good and Yahoo's docs suck so I created one: http://chstocksearch.herokuapp.com/welcome

Comment: This URL has been changed to: http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=yahoo&region=IN&lang=en-UK&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback

Comment: @VermaJr. where can I find the documentation for this API, in case the URL should change again? How did you know the new URL?

Comment: You could do fuzzy search using this https://rapidapi.com/logicione/api/stock-ticker-security-and-company-search-database?endpoint=apiendpoint_c9c32d57-dede-4507-b180-9ea4a61ebb02

Answer (score 33):

Google Finance does let you retrieve up to 100 stock quotes at once using the following URL:

www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=[ticker1],[ticker2],...,[tickern]

For example:

www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=C,JPM,AIG

Someone has deciphered the available fields here:

http://qsb-mac.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Vermilion/Modules/StockQuoter/StockQuoter.py

The current price ("l") is real-time and the delay is on par with Yahoo Finance.  There are a few quirks you should be aware of.  A handful of stocks require an exchange prefix.  For example, if you query "BTIM", you'll get a "Bad Request" error but "AMEX:BTIM" works.  A few stocks don't work even with the exchange prefix.  For example, querying "FTWRD" and "NASDAQ:FTWRD" both generate "Bad Request" errors even though Google Finance does have information for this NASDAQ stock.

The "el" field, if present, tells you the current pre-market or after-hours price.

Comment: Moved to http://qsb-mac-plugins.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/stock-quoter/trunk/StockQuoter.py

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the Google Finance API is deprecated and will be shutdown on 20 October 2012 https://developers.google.com/finance

Comment: Yes having a look and google finance is now depricated and not open for business. Given googles track record closing apis I would be very hesitant to base a business or app on it unless you had a contract and sla with them

Comment: Any new docs?
Service still works, Looking for a stock search too :) like yahoo one

Answer (score 25):

You can send an HTTP request to **http://finance.yahoo.com** requesting symbols, names, quotes, and all sorts of other data. Data is returned as a **.CSV** so you can request multiple symbols in one query.

So if you send:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MSFT+F+ATT&f=sn
```

You'll get back something like:

```
"MSFT","Microsoft Corp"
"F","FORD MOTOR CO"
"ATT","AT&T"
```

Here is an **article** called [Downloading Yahoo Data](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) which **includes the various tags** used to request the data.

Comment: Unfortunately, finding the company name from a symbol is easy. I'm looking for a way to automate a batch-lookup of ticker symbols from a list of company names. Google has by far the best search, I can find the symbol for almost any company in my list without having to manually search, but Google has rate-limiting and will give you a 503 error after about 1000 requests.

Comment: not an answer, but useful for the domain

Comment: looks like that api usage has legal issues. When opening  [Downloading Yahoo Data] one will see a note of Yahoo that using their service in those way is illegal

Comment: You can see the same interface documented at http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/. Or search for the original at http://archive.org.

Answer (score 23):

The NASDAQ site hosts separate CSV lists for ticker symbols in each stock exchange (NYSE, AMEX and NASDAQ). You need to complete the captcha and get the CSV dump.

http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx

Answer (score 9):

If you didn't want to sign up for a service, I'd probably go back to the exchanges themselves; most of them aren't CAPTCHAed yet...

The symbol lookup page for:

- [NYSE](http://www.nyse.com/) is at http://www.nyse.com/interface/html/SymbolLookup.html
- [NASDAQ](http://www.nasdaq.com/) is at http://www.nasdaq.com/asp/NasdaqSymLookup2.asp?mode=stock
- [London Stock Exchange](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/) is at http://www.londonstockexchange.com/en-gb/pricesnews/prices/Trigger/genericsearch.htm
- [ASX](http://www.asx.com.au/) is at http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/codeLookup.do

etc...

Comment: Better yet, skip symbol lookup at the exchange sites -- just screen-scrape their full listings into your own local table and do the lookup yourself.

Comment: @John Pirie: Yeah, that too... :-)

Answer (score 7):

Use YQL and you don't need to worry. It's a query language by Yahoo and you can get all the stock data including the name of the company for the ticker. It's a REST API and it returns the results via XML or JSON.  I have a full tutorial and source code on my site take a look: http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo-stock-symbol-lookup/

Comment: That looks nice but it returns a result with a limit of 10 results. Any chance of getting more?

Answer (score 6):

Currently, the NASDAQ web site publicly provides CSV files containing bulk listings  -- it is broken up by first letter.

> http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=A&render=download

Answer (score 2):

Google Finance has an API - you probably have to apply for a developers key, but at least you'd save yourself the hassle of screen-scraping: http://code.google.com/apis/finance/reference.html

Comment: Google is now depricated an not longer open for business

Answer (score 1):

Your best bets are probably going with one of the other lookup services (still screen-scraping), and checking whether they don't require CAPTCHAs.

- [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/)
- [MSN Money](http://moneycentral.msn.com/investor/common/find.asp)
- [AlphaTrade Finance](http://finance.alphatrade.com/quotes/symbol_lookup)

The last appears the least likely to require a CAPTCHA at any point, but it's worth checking all three.

Answer (score 0):

Use YQL: a sql-like language to retrieve stuff from public api's:
[YQL Console (external link)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22%29)

It gives you a nice XML file to work with!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Company Search" operation in the Company Fundamentals API here: http://www.mergent.com/servius/