# fail to get yahoo stock quote by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, yahoo

I am trying to get Yahoo stock quote in the following way. but it does not work, can anyone tell where is wrong. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn").click(function(event){
              alert(document.forms[0].ticker.value);
              $("#stockPrice").load("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=ibm #yfs_l10_ibm").text(); 
     });
 });

    </script>
<body>


<form name="myForm">
Ticker: <input type="text" name="ticker" id="ticker"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="get quote"/>
</form>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

I changed from

```
$("#stockPrice").load("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=ibm #yfs_l10_ibm).text()
```

to

```
$("#stockPrice").load("ibm.dat"),text()
```

and copied the data to ibm.dat But I still have the following problem.

> Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
>   Line: 255
>   Char: 5
>   Code: 0
>   URI: file:///C:/Javascripts/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.js

any idea?

Comment: is there a question? what is wrong

Comment: You need to clean up this question a little bit, so that we can understand a little more clearly what you are asking.

Comment: New visitors to StackOverflow often find this link helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: What is the symptom?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: why do you have a cardinal and a name after the url?

Comment: sorry!  I can't paste the whole code ... working on it

Comment: @yoda: "In jQuery 1.2 you can now specify a jQuery selector in the URL. Doing so will filter the incoming HTML document, only injecting the elements that match the selector."

Comment: You can't `.load()` from a different URL than your original server.  You need to look into the JSON callback stuff.

Comment: On a side note, there isn't a free live stock market feed available (that I know of)... but I did find this article interesting (http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/01/12/google-to-stream-free-live-nyse-stock-quotes-and-share-prices/). I guess nothing came of it since it's dated Jan 2007.

Comment: Also check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885456/stock-ticker-symbol-lookup-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming you meant it doesnt work. thats probably because you are trying to do cross domain ajax request which is prohibited. see http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/

Comment: In addition, if you want it to work, create a php/asp page that uses "Curl" to fetch the information you want and retrieve it via $.ajax or other method in jQuery.