# I need a sql db that has all the stock symbols on the US market. ANYONE?

Tags: database, public, stock

That is pretty much it. I need a .sql file with all the stock symbols and company names matched up for an autocomplete function I'm writing. ANYONE?

Comment: How up-to-date does it have to be? How much can you pay?

Comment: Not off-topic, this is a typical programming problem (where to get reference data to help the app function better).

Comment: Have you tried nasdaq (http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx)?  Just `bulk insert` the csv file daily or weekly.  Have you tried google or yahoo finance sites?

Answer (score 2):

Well i dont know about a downloadable .sql file but there are numerous free and paid API's you could use to get the data for import into your db. Check out this similar questions for some options: [Stock ticker symbol lookup API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885456/stock-ticker-symbol-lookup-api)

I think i would go this route and maybe run a background process that does an update from the API every now and then so that you always have all the symbols up to date.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx. This page contains company list from NASDAQ, AMEX and NYSE. You can then read in CSV data and store it as sql.

Answer (score 1):

I use the python package [pytickersymbols](https://github.com/portfolioplus/pytickersymbols). The package offers an offline collection of stocks with metadata like google and yahoo symbols.

```
from pytickersymbols import PyTickerSymbols

stock_data = PyTickerSymbols()
nasdaq_stocks = list(stock_data.get_stocks_by_index('NASDAQ 100'))
sp500_stocks = list(stock_data.get_stocks_by_index('S&P 500'))
sp100_stocks = list(stock_data.get_stocks_by_index('S&P 100'))
```

In the repository, you can also find a YAML file which is maybe useful for a SQL file creation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Company Fundamentals API at http://www.mergent.com/servius - should be pretty easy to extract the list from there.