# YQL Table Error

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml, yql

I have been using a specific YQL call in an app I am building for Blackberry Playbook.  Specfically the call is `select * from yahoo.finance.stocks where symbol ="ABF.L"`  Previously this returned a field called CompanyName which in the case above would return "Associated British Foods".  Recently this call in YQL console returns:

```
"results": {
   "stock": {
    "symbol": "ABF.L",
    "CompanyName": "",
    "start": "2003-01-01",
    "end": "2012-02-13",
    "Sector": "Consumer Goods",
    "Industry": "Food - Major Diversified",
    "FullTimeEmployees": "102000"
   }
```

This occurs no matter what stock symbol is used. Consequently, my app now shows '()' on the screen when it should in fact show (Associated British Foods).

I have posted messaged on the Yahoo Developer Site regarding this problem but as yet no reply.  Can anybody suggest a fix or alternate solution to overcome this problem?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `yahoo.finance.stocks` YQL table is not working very well anymore. (It's a community table and is not an official API from Yahoo.)

The Google stock table may work as a better option. See this SO question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230951/9965

Comment: many thanks for the input.  My app is an MXML app built in Flash Builder 4.6.  The call to the google.igoogle is written as follows;