# Retrieving stock data

Tags: python, google-play, stock, stocks

I'm trying to retrieve stock data in real-time using Python.  As of now I am using the yahoo-finance module which I believe is 15 minutes behind.  Also, I can't retrieve the company name with this module.  I need to be able to retrieve current price, opening price, and company name, using just the ticker code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I answered your question but in the future do some work yourself. This was all stuff you could have easily searched for yourself.

Comment: @DanielCentore thank you for your response.  Everything I have found on myself except how to find the company t name... Which you have provided... I was simply providing more information on what I was doing.

Comment: That was very unclear. Make sure your questions are well formed and don't lead to confusion. This is a volunteer site.

Comment: That's for the input... I'm falling a sleep over here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Company name given the ticker symbol:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/885557/998251

Opening/Closing Price are given when you use yahoo.get_historical. [Manual](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.1.4)

You're not going to get much less than 15 minute lag for free. To get truly realtime you need to pay some serious cash.

Answer (score 0):

This should return current price ATM

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def stock_price(symbol: str = "AAPL") -> str:
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    class_ = "My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px) W(100%)"
    return soup.find("div", class_=class_).find("fin-streamer").text

current_price = stock_price('AAPL')
```