# Ticker finder on Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

How to find ticker from stock name on Google finance. You can do the opposite by typing =GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker,"name") but the problem is you can find the company name faster than the ticker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stock ticker symbol lookup API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885456/stock-ticker-symbol-lookup-api)